# XMLParser in MapReduce Program failing with the Message: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Tags: java, hadoop, xml-parsing, mapreduce

I've been performing distributed XML parsing on a hadoop cluster. I am using [this XmlInputFormat](https://github.com/studhadoop/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/XmlParser11.java) in my map-reduce programs. It worked pretty well and my sincere thanks to that contributor.

But, here is the issue that i ran into:

While testing this few map-red jobs were failing with the below XMLStreamException.

```
java.io.IOException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[21,69]
Message: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.XMLRecordCount$Map.map(XMLRecordCount.java:197)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.XMLRecordCount$Map.map(XMLRecordCount.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:214)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[21,69]
Message: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:594)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.XMLRecordCount$Map.map(XMLRecordCount.java:168)
```

As per my understanding this is being caused because of the character & in the data. For example - `"<name>Alen & Bob </name>"`

I am dealing with the logs which contain above such data. But because of this, the entire job is failing.

I can think of pre-processing as a solution but may not be an efficient option for me.

Could you suggest me an approach by which i can skip such bad records / or just replace such character in Java XML api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `map` function (in [the example](https://github.com/studhadoop/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/XmlParser11.java) you posted), instead of catching and rethrowing any exception, just catch the `XMLStreamException` and do nothing in the catch block. Nothing will be emitted and the job won't fail. You probably want to increase a counter to keep track of invalid records, though.

Pseudo Code:

```
  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper.Context context) throws IOException
      try {
          XMLStreamReader reader = ...
          context.write(...);
      } catch(XMLStreamException e){
            // do nothing
            context.getCounter(INVALID_RECORDS).increment(1);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably do this if you are using the XmlParser11.java as you have mentioned - You can replace the '&' in the document string object something like:

```
document = document.replace("&", "your_desired_working_string_here");
...
...
XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new
                      ByteArrayInputStream(document.getBytes()));
```

and then at the time of emitting from map() you can again replace

`"your_desired_working_string_here"` with `'&'`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `&` in your XML, try using `&amp;` . i.e. instead of `<name>Alen & Bob </name>` have `<name>Alen &amp; Bob </name>`